# CodeIgniter - Field in database gets updated multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to update the views of a particular page by incrementing it in the database. Here's the code:

```
function increment_views($id)
{
    $this->db->where('UID',$id);
    $this->db->set('`Views`', 'Views+1', FALSE);
    if($this->db->update('articles'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

It updates 1 time (as intented) when I echo something in my controller. If I just load my views and echo nothing in the controller, it updates the views like 4 and sometimes 5 times.

**Edit:** Found the problem. When the url has a trailing slash, the increment is abnormal otherwise it just increments by 1 as it should. The problem is that I need the trailing slash for the disqus plugin to work. Here's my .htaccess file:

```
#turn mod_rewrite engine on.
RewriteEngine On
#set the base for urls here to /
RewriteBase /codzer

#adds a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 


### if the is not a request for an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# rewrite to index.php passing the URI as a path, QSA will preserve the existing query string
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any idea where I might be wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I assume `increment_views` is in your model coding somewhere. I suggest you post where the function is being called (at the view level?) Also add logging to the function and where the function is being called to track down where and when it's being called.

Comment: @AaronW. The function is being called in the controller. It is not passed to the view. I will log the function and post back the results.

Comment: Is it called in a constructor? Are you using ajax calls that may call the controller more than once?

Comment: No, it's not being called in the constructor. I removed the disqus code and now it increments by only 2. I removed every script in the view but it still increments by 2. I think the index function of the controller is being called multiple times but no idea from where.

Comment: Is your page being redirected maybe, or called using AJAX? Inspect it using the network tab in chrome/firefox.